# An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4

An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
this is my code where  exception is showing at runtime.
Iam using .net framework 4.5 and sqlserver2008r2.
so can anyone can help me to get out of this  problem.

Stack Trace:

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.Legacy.SqlCeProviderServices..ctor() +0
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.Legacy.SqlCeProviderServices..cctor() +44

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.Legacy.SqlCeProviderServices' threw an exception.]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(RtFieldInfo field, Object instance, RuntimeType fieldType, RuntimeType declaringType, Boolean& domainInitialized) +0
   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.UnsafeGetValue(Object obj) +124
   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +132
   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj) +21
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.MemberInfoExtensions.GetValue(MemberInfo memberInfo) +132
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType) +194
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__2(ProviderElement e) +109
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +460
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1() +135
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DbProviderServices() +40
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices() +59
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name) +126
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t) +110
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +210
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +60
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +250
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +63
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver) +141
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model) +124
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString) +103
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`6..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString) +37
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema) +45
   Srismiles.Models.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() in f:\Srismiles\Srismiles\Srismiles\Models\IdentityModels.cs:32
   Srismiles.Logic.RoleActions.AddUserAndRole() in f:\Srismiles\Srismiles\Srismiles\Logic\RoleActions.cs:17
   Srismiles.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Srismiles\Srismiles\Srismiles\Global.asax.cs:29

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9935033
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: Please show the *full* stack trace - it will almost certainly include an `InnerException` giving more information.

Comment: i have added my stack trace

Comment: Hmm. What kind of connection are you trying to use? This appears to be using SqlCeProviderServices, or at least loading it. I'm afraid I don't have much experience in this area, but at least you've provided more information which may enable someone else to help you now.

Comment: ok thank u -Jon Skeet for your response i will post the solution for the problem once i get rid of it

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely try to do 2 things:

- Update EF packages to the latest version in **all projects** (**Update-Package EntityFramework** will work for you in package console)
- Use **Update-Database** command in all projects that have data context on your database

I faced the same problem right now and it was solved via these steps.